# Is there any possibility I could use WD40 to unstick a furnace fan center relay?

Tags: relay, fans

I've recently run into an issue this winter, where the fan center relay in the furnace for the house I'm living in has begun to stick closed, when the thermostats call it for heat.

It is a hydronic system, where there are 3 zones. One for the downstairs, one for the majority of the upstairs, and one for the master bedroom upstairs.

And I know it's sticking, because when I go down to try and turn the heat on, the fan center relay has a consistent buzzing.
But when I tap its outer casing hard enough with a hammer, it unsticks, stops buzzing, and the heat turns on.

+1 for percussive maintenance, right?

Anyways, my question is whether I can open the casing for the FCR, and spray the internals with WD40 in order to help it more consistently switch over?

I've tried to get a quote from my HVAC tech, but he's not certain how much it would end up costing, since the furnace was installed in the 60s or 70s, and he's worried that any parts he sources won't be fully compatible, and/or that multiple parts of the furnace which are currently fragile might fail during the replacement procedure.

It's supposed to get to -10 *C this week, and I'd prefer the heating to be operating when that happens :(

Comment: Welcome.  Got maybe a photo of the suspect part?  it's difficutt to say without details.

Comment: Hank Hill, is that you?

Comment: WD-40 is not a lubricant and really shouldn't be used as one. It will work as a lubricant for a brief while, then dry up and need to be replaced. Use a proper lubricant oil.

Comment: WD-40 is pretty much snake oil.  It was developed as a missile polish, and is now marketed for anywhere you want oily stuff to spray out of a can. It is not lubricant, it is not penetrating oil.   **What it definitely IS, is plastic dissolver. I've had many plastic things deteriorate and fail after contact with WD-40**. The same will happen to your relay.  It is a poor choice for any of the uses it is put to. Throw it away unless you feel you have a chance of acquiring an Atlas missile.

Comment: Looks like your question was answered but that doesn't solve your problem. If you're willing to remove the relay and open it up why not just replace it. Jack's answer is good,  if you post a photo of the relay you may get an even better answer.

Comment: TBH, wd40 would probably get you though the holidays, at the cost of long life, but considering it sounds like the part's at end of life, I don't see any major downsides compared to the situation at-hand.  Maybe i'm weird, but I use wd40 all the time. Nothing better to cleanout a deadbolt cylinder, rusty/dusty hinges, remove many kinds of gunk, keep your bike chain clean and rust-free, clean and lubricate light bulb sockets,  etc. I still use 3in1 a lot, it pays to know what to apply to different materials.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, I won't use wd-40 then. And I'll take a picture the next time I go and smack it lol it's in the downstairs suite, and the guys who live down there are away a lot, and have less mechanical experience than even I do, so I have to wait for them to be home to go down there and do it myself.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to spray any liquid in the relay That will only collect dust and dirt and clog it up even move. The relay contacts could be sticking and it's always a good idea to cleaned them off with some emery paper. If you can open the case, clean everything out especially the insides of the coil and the outsides of the plunger if you can get to them with emery paper. They have probably rusted a bit.
I would have to guess that a replacement relay would be pretty easy to find. If you can remove it, take it to a refrigeration repair or appliance repair shop and they could probably match one up.

Comment: Hmm, okay, good to know. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

### There is no right chemical for repairing a relay contact

Most of the time you are dealing with a $6 relay, and the easy course of action is simply to replace it.

I gather you have more experience with spraying things from a spray can, than you do identifying, acquiring and replacing relays.  But this really boils down to experience: If it were the other way 'round, you would already have replaced the relay obviously.  This is just a cognitive bias, the "if all you have is a hammer, all the world looks like a nail" syndrome. Realize it and overcome it.

### WD-40 is missile polish.

WD-40 has no legitimate use except to [polish your missile](https://www.thoughtco.com/wd-40-1992659).  All other uses are accidental and WD-40 is an inferior choice for those uses. It's only hyped up because of a massive ad campaign.  It's sort of like the "crypto" of chemicals lol.

When you want penetrating oil, use penetrating oil like Kroil or Liquid Wrench. When you want a light machine oil, use one such as 3-in-1.

However, WD-40 is notorious for slowly destroying plastic parts. It solves the immediate problem, but then 3 months later, exposed plastics or adhesives deteriorate. It would be a terrible choice on a relay for this reason alone, but also [its flammability](https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/electric-breaker-making-crackling-sound-when-on.745135/post-6831756).

Comment: Chemically speaking, WD-40 is just heavy kerosene/light diesel (plus a spray can). That pretty much defines all of its properties and reasonable uses.

Comment: WD-40 also contains highly flammable solvents, and relays make sparks.

Answer (score 0):

Most relays have simple function
When powered on they close the contact.
When no power the spring opens the contacts.
It is possible that over time and with some humidity the mechanical part has some rust and it is partially stuck. Using lubricant could help.

It is also possible that the coil does not get enough power to operate. Check the voltage on the coil.

If it is buzzing and not closing the contact it is the coil.

If it is stuck closed it is the spring.

Comment: So it's the coil! Okay, good to know. I'll try and open the casing and apply an appropriate lubricant to the coil.

Comment: @Tallguy5292 after getting the lectures on WD40, go ahead use few drops (do not spray all over) on the mechanism. Lubricating the coil will not help, it is electromagnet, so only power is the question

Comment: Ohhh, okay. I'll try a few drops then. So far, tapping it with a hammer seems to be working. I just have to do it every time I want the heat to turn on 

Answer (score 0):

There is a substance known as "contact cleaner"  which electronic repair folks used to use to clean switches and relays. If you are convinced that cleaning is actually needed, I'd suggest you go looking for that. Warning: flammable until it evaporated.

Depending on the type of relay, it may also be possible to touch up the relay contacts with an emery board.

But as others have said, there are other possible failure mechanisms. So I wouldn't assume this will be the fix. Repair is a process of eliminating possibilities until you find the cause.